# Iterative function with $z_{n+2}$

Tags: functions, special-functions, fractals

I'm currently playing arround with my custom fractal renderer and on Math SE in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5705/148261) Américo suggested the following function:

$z_{n+2}=z_{n+1}^{3}+c^{z_{n}}$

But to get the first value I'd need $z_{n+1}$, but for this I'd need $z_{n-1}$ and so on. How can I iterate this function?

Comment: You can set $z_0$ and $z_1$ to some values and compute the rest of $z_n$ from there.

Comment: Thank you. Add it as an aswer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c$$

In Mandelbrot's sequence, $z_0$ is defined to be $0$. The definition of $z_{n+1}$ requires only $z_n$ to be defined, so a single starting value, $z_0$, is enough to define $z_n$ for all $n$.

---

$$z_{n+2}=z_{n+1}^{3}+c^{z_{n}}$$

In this sequence, to define $z_{n+2}$, you need both $z_{n+1}$ and $z_n$ to be defined. So, to define $z_n$ for all $n$, you need two starting values: $z_0$ and $z_1$. They can be of any value, but changing them will change the rest of the sequence.